# How to create a zip in gitlab using gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: zip, gitlab-ci, archive, subdirectory

I have committed certain .pdf files in gitlab repository. I am continuously adding files in different sub-directories. For each and every sub-directory I want to write a yml, which will allow me to download that particular sub-directory in .zip format with the directory name as file name. What to write ?

I have tried using archive command and it does not work, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing there is only one level of sub-directories the following works:

```yaml
zip_files:
  image: alpine
  before_script:
    - apk add --update zip
  script:
    - |
     for d in */ ; do
       cd $d; zip -r ../${d%/}.zip *; cd ..
     done
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - '*.zip'
```